# In a webpage while scraping for phone numbers how should I ignore the following swap.js

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

```
         source_trackers: [{
        id: 497887186,
        referrer_tracking_source: "landing_url",
        landing_tracking_source: "/call.html",
        referrer_keys: ["landing_url"],
        swap_targets: ["7132302200"],
        advanced_swap_targets: {
            "713-230-2200": "###phone###"
        },
        number: {
            national: "(713) 999-6945",
            national_string: "7139996945",
            international: "+1 713-999-6945",
            e164: "+17139996945",
            formats: {}
        }
```

Site in question is https://whlaw.com/

I am using this code to extract the phone numbers from each page of the site...its not complete yet so any  help on that would be appreciated

```
import scrapy
import re


class DrizzySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_all = True
    name = 'drizzy'
    allowed_domains = ['whlaw.com']
    start_urls = ['https://whlaw.com/houston-tx-car-accident-results-in-injuries-on- 
    willow-glen-dr-near-martin-luther-king-blvd/']


 def parse(self, response):
     number = response.xpath('//body').re(r"\(?[0-9]{3}\)?(?:\-|\s|\.)?[0-9]{3}(?:\-|\.)[0-9]{4}")
```

print (number)

Comment: And what is the output? Is that json you provide is you need or you got?

Comment: output is['(713) 230-2200', '(713) 230-2200', '713-230-2200', '713-230-2200', '713-230-2200']

Comment: ['(713) 230-2200', '(713) 230-2200', '713-230-2200', '713-230-2200', '713-230-2200'] it just repeats itself

Comment: problem here is I think the swap.js in the site replaces every number that is being scraped with 713-230-2200

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
import scrapy
import json

class Test(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['whlaw.com']

    headers = {
        "authority": "js.callrail.com",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.94 Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36",
        "content-type": "text/plain",
        "origin": "https://whlaw.com",
        "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "referer": "https://whlaw.com/",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
    }

    body = '{"cid":null,"uuid":"82c63141-59bc-43bd-8eab-7c19e660ff4f","ref":"direct","landing":"https://whlaw.com/houston-tx-car-accident-results-in-injuries-on-willow-glen-dr-near-martin-luther-king-blvd/","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.94 Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36","record_pageview":true,"all_formats":true,"ids":[531239316],"google_content_cookies":"","GoogleAnalytics__ga":"GA1.2.2069232432.1626503501","Custom_SOURCE_SOURCE":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_MEDIUM":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_CAMPAIGN":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_ADGROUP":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_CONTENT":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_TERM":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_NETWORK":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_CAMPAIGNID":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_ADGROUPID":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_TERMID":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_PLACEMENT":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_MOBILE":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_DEVICE":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_DEVICEMODEL":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_MATCH":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_ADPOSITION":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_NOTE":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_GCLID":"NA","Custom_SOURCE_MSCLKID":"NA","ga":"GA1.2.2069232432.1626503501","utma":null,"utmb":null,"utmc":null,"utmv":null,"utmx":null,"utmz":null,"perf":{}}'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://js.callrail.com/group/0/245c27cd228c2bd1b7e1/12/swap_session.json'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, method='POST', headers=self.headers, body=self.body)

    def parse(self, response):
        json_data = json.loads(response.body)
        phone_number = json_data.get('a').get('531239316').get('7132302200').get('national')
        yield {
            'phone_number':phone_number
        }
```

Comment: Can the code be written so that the output would be in a CSV file
E

Comment: Yes, you can yield the phone number and then can save the csv file by running this command scrapy crawl <spider name> -o file.csv. Would you mind to accept the answer if it helped you?

Comment: getting a NameError in your code as of now....its the yield Request

Comment: [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 129, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "C:\Users\sinha\Desktop\Mums\Law\Law\spiders\test.py", line 29, in start_requests
    yield Request(url=url, method='POST', headers=self.headers, body=self.body)
NameError: name 'Request' is not defined

Comment: I have modified the solution. Please check above & let me know if it works for you.